# How to access the last element in the list values in a dictionary that contain lists as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For example:

```
dictionary = {'a':[3,0], 'b':[5,0]}
```

If I'm writing an if-statement to check whether or not the last element of the list value pairs is zero, how should I access it?

Comment: `all([d[key][-1] == 0 for key in d])` prints `True` for your test case, `False` if either one or both last items are not `0`.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks man, this seemed to resolve the issue!

Comment: Great; I've worked it out as a full answer so you can use it in a single test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionary by using the [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) operation to return pairs of key/values and handle them as you wish. One example is listed below.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v[-1] == 0:
        print('{} -> {}'.format(k, v))

a -> [3, 0]
b -> [5, 0]
```

Comment: I didn't even think about this, thanks! Since the dictionary in my case is always updating with new values, a for loop solves my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the last element in a list with `list_name[-1]`.

Your if statement should look something like this:

```
if dictionary[key_name][-1] == 0:
    # todo
```

**Output:**

```
>>> dict = {'a':[3,0], 'b':[5,0]}
>>> dict['a'][-1]
0
>>> print(dict['a'][-1] == 0)
True
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, now I feel stupid for not seeing the logic for it.

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension

```
[value[-1] == 0 for _,value in dictionary.items()]
```

returns a list of `True` and `False` values for each of the last items in the dict values. For your test dictionary it returns

```
[True, True]
```

Next, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) on the list to test if they indeed are all `True`:

```
all([value[-1] == 0 for _,value in dictionary.items()])
```

which returns a single boolean `True` or `False`. (And here it'd return `True` of course.)